# How to run IBM Rational Rose v 7.0 on Windows 8/10 (incompatibility bag)

Tags: windows-10, compatibility

I have installed `IBM Rational Rose v 7.0.0 2006` on Windows 10. When I try to run IBM Rational Rose Enterprise `exe` file it crashes with the following error:

> Rational Rose Visual Modelling Tool has stopped working.
>   Windows is checking for a solution to the problem...

Picture:
[image]

And then immediately after that error I receive the following:

> Rational Rose Visual Modelling Tool has stopped working.
>   A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.
>   Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is avaiable.

Picture:
[image]

If I run the program in compatibility mode for `Windows XP (SP3)`, I receive the following error:

> RegUtil::KeyImage -- The parameter is incorrect.

Picture:
[image]

What might be a problem? How to resolve such incompatibility issue?

Comment: You can't.  Compatibility Mode works by using a shim, that in most cases, solves known compatibility problems with applications and newer version of Windows (basically any version after Windows XP).  In this case the software only likely supports 32-bit operating systems anyways.  You could run this in a Windows XP virtual machine though.

Comment: That is something you will have to research on your own.  I just attempted to present you with information about how compatibility mode works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/rational/rose_7004_iFix003/Rose_Windows_Release_Notes_v7.0.0.4_IFIX03.doc

> ### Platform support
>
> #### Supported Operating Systems
>
> - Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise 32 bit and 64bit
> - Microsoft Windows 7 Professional 32 bit and 64bit
> - Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit and 64bit
> - Microsoft Windows XP Professional

Note: Rose works as a 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS.

1. Right-click the Rational Rose icon and click Properties
2. Go to the Compatibility tab
3. Click Change Setting For All Users
4. On Run This Program in Compatibility Mode for:
5. Change to *Windows Vista (Service Pack 2)*
6. Click Apply and OK.